# Get Whatsapp share counts

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, whatsapp

I'm developing a web project using ASP.NET. At the article page it show social share links and share counts. (Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and of course Whatsapp)

I couldnt find any thing on the net about Whatsapp share counts; but a website somehow displays it. You can check it [here](http://onedio.co).

How can I get this?

Comment: Hi, how are you calculating count for others then? Answer is in front of you. Whichever framework you use or library, share function might be returning with 2 callbacks success and error. In the success callback function just hit the entry in database about which ID post you just shared. Let me know your thoughts....

Comment: I looked up network tab, and found that they could be using custom tracking system for WhatsApp share counts.